# How to find Cache Hit or Miss given specific Hexadecimal Values?

Tags: c, caching, bit

I have to write a C code that states whether a hex number has cache hit or miss depending on the following four variables:
1. The size of address used in the cache (bit)
2. The number of index bits (S = 2<sup>s</sup> is the number of sets)
3. The number of line bits (E = 2<sup>e</sup> is the number of lines)
4. The size of block bits (B = 2<sup>b</sup> is the block size)

Let's say the size of the address is 64, the number of index bits is 4, number of line bits is 0, the size of block bits is 4. (64,4,0,4)

How do I find whether the following hexadecimal values have a cache hit or miss
10
20
22
18
E10
210
12

I don't care so much about the specific answer, but rather how to find the answers. How does cache hit or miss vary depending on the four (64,4,0,4) numbers?

Comment: Identifying the bits in an address that correspond to each field is simple. The low b bits of the address are the byte within the block. The next s bits identify the cache set. (The remaining bits form a “tag” that is used to identify the address when it is held in a cache line in the set.) However, this information alone cannot determine whether there is a hit or a miss. To know that, you need to know what is in cache already. Take the bits that identify the cache set. Look at the lines in that cache set. If the cache set contains a line for that address, it is a hit. Otherwise, it is a miss.

Comment: thank you eric. do you know of any online resources to learn about cache hit or miss. i tried to google it, but couldnt find a proper video